# How to replace Fragment from dialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a simple game that on, certain fragments, when the back button is pressed, it'll show a dialogFragment asking to exit, continue or retry the game. When the retry button is pressed, the current fragment, on the activity, should be replaced but I keep getting "Activity has been destroyed" error.

**OnBackPressed**

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);

        Bundle currentFragmentArguments = currentFragment.getArguments();

        if (currentFragmentArguments != null)
                currentPlayer = (Players)currentFragmentArguments.getSerializable("currentPlayer");

        //if not on last fragment(fight) then check if can go back to last fragment
        if (!currentFragment.getTag().contains("fight"))
        {
            // Is there more than one fragment saved(1 is main menu fragment) and is player 1?
            // Player 2 can only go back when drawing
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1  && 
                    (currentPlayer == null || currentPlayer.equals(Players.p1)))
            {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }

            //Player 2 can't go back if picking weapon
            else if (currentFragment.equals(Players.p2)
                    && !currentFragment.getTag().contains("weapon"))
            {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }

            else
            {
                //show to exit or go back to main menu

                ShowDialog(); //<-- This is the important part
            }
        }

        else
        {    
            ShowDialog(); //<-- This is the important part
        }
    }
```

**ShowDialog**

```
@Override
    public void ShowDialog()
    {
        Dialog d = new Dialog();

        d.SetDialogTitle("About to exit...");

        d.show(getFragmentManager(), "pauseDialog");
    }
```

**Restart button listener (Located on the dialogFragment)**

```
restartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dialogStateTxt = DialogStates.Restart.toString();

                dismiss();

                Main main = new Main();

                main.RestartGame();
            }
        });
```

**RestartGame**

```
@Override
    public void RestartGame()
    {
       MainMenuFragment mainMenuFragment = new MainMenuFragment();

        fragmentConfig.ReplaceFragment(mainMenuFragment, android.R.id.content,
                getFragmentManager(), mainMenuFragment.GetTag(), false);
    }
```

**ReplaceFragment (This is where the error is fired)**

```
public void ReplaceFragment(Fragment fragment, int contentId, FragmentManager fragmentManager,
                                String fragmentTag, boolean shouldAddToBackStack)
    {
        fragmentTrans = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if (shouldAddToBackStack)
        {
            fragmentTrans.addToBackStack(fragmentTag);
        }

        fragmentTrans.replace(contentId, fragment, fragmentTag);

        fragmentTrans.commit();
    }
```

**Logcat**

```
    Process: retroroots.alphadraja, PID: 24440

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1345)

    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:597)

    at android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:575)

    at retroroots.alphadraja.CanisterEngine.Android.Fragment.FragmentConfig.ReplaceFragment(FragmentConfig.java:70)

    at retroroots.alphadraja.Main.RestartGame(Main.java:71)

    at retroroots.alphadraja.CanisterEngine.Android.Widgets.Dialog$2.onClick(Dialog.java:63)

    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4473)

    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18472)

    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Kinda new to android development and fixing this might teach me a few things.

Also, please explain your answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it by declaring `RestartGame` on a fragment instead of the main activity. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Don't let `super.onBackPressed()` called if you're showing a `fragment`. Execute it only when user clicks on exit. That is probably causing your `Activity` to be destroyed.

Comment: That's a bit difficult, the whole game(app) is built on fragments. Can you give me an example?

Comment: When back button is pressed and your dialog is created, call super.onBackPressed() only inside the onClickListener of the exit button.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you were saying. I'm not using super.onBackPressed()

Comment: I've updated my question. I added OnBackPressed definition

Comment: Maybe this is due to calling dismiss before main.RestartGame().

Comment: Tried commenting it and still get the same error. I've added the logcat, hope that helps

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and still getting the same error. Placed it on OnDetach on every fragment that calls the dialog. This is quite the problem :/